Reference for the densitiy of $C_c(D,\mathbb{R}^d)$ in $C_0(D,\mathbb{R}^d)$
Is there a (standard) reference for the following statement:
Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be open and bounded. Then, $C_c(D,\mathbb{R}^d)$ is dense in $C_0(D,\mathbb{R}^d)$ w.r.t. the supremum norm, where
$C_c(D,\mathbb{R}^d):=\{V \in C(D,\mathbb{R}^d): supp(V) \text{ compact in } D\}$ and $C_0(D,\mathbb{R}^d):=\{V \in C(D,\mathbb{R}^d): \forall \epsilon > 0~ \exists K \subset D \text{ compact such that } |V(x)| < \epsilon \text{ for all } x \in D \setminus K \}$.

Have you looked at Rudin's book? This is an easy application of Urysohn's lemma

Thanks! Do you now, where I can find a smooth version of Urysohn's lemma, where I get a $C_c^{\infty}$-function?

I am not aware of such version. However, you can use mollifiers to approximate $C_c$ functions by $C_c^\infty$ functions

Thanks again! Actually, I found references for both statements in the book "Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications" of Folland (see 4.35 and 8.18).
